# W2K INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE, with System Commander

Tags: boot, windows-2000

I have a system that was originally had Win NT. I added System Commander (SC7) and then added W2K. The relevant partitions are:

- 0 - Primary - MultiFAT (Has Win NT, mapped to C:)
- 1 - Extended - with many logical partitions:
- 1.1 NTFS which has W2K and is mapped to D:
- 1.2 other logical partitions which are irrelevant to this

D: was getting full. It needed room for virus definitions and Windows upgrades. In the past, I had simple used SC7 to resize D: without problems. So I did it again this time. However, upon finishing, I got the message "Unable to create partition". It also marked the partition as unformatted. I checked that the files on the disk were still there using SC7's  Partition Explorer, and they were there. I continued and the system managed to boot up fine anyways.

Then I rebooted the system again. This time, I got a message saying "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE". I went back in to SC7 and to Partition Commander, and it was still saying that the partition was unformatted but the Partition Explorer still showed the files on the system. I finally decided to resize the partition again, figuring that this would force a rewrite of the partition information.

That seemed to work, until I had to reboot again. Now I can't see the files using Partition Explorer, and the Resize button is now disabled.

What now?

Comment: Windows 2000 is no longer supported by Microsoft at all, and so therefore is no longer receiving security updates (amongst other things).  You really need to upgrade to at least Windows XP, and ideally Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, you buy me that and I'll install it. :)
But that doesn't help me solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start from scratch.  Assuming you have a backup, delete all the partitions, then re-create them and restore files from backup.  If you don't have a backup, rescue what files you can (using various tools freely available or using a recovery service) and then rebuild the partitions from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Because I this computer had no access to the Internet, because it couldn't boot, I was unable to take advantage of any online service. I had to stick with a physical media such as a CD-ROM. I ended up buying Partition Commander 10, which luckily has a new feature of being able to repair the MBR and partition records. It worked.